# mb_strtolower and utf8 strings

Tags: php, arrays

As you know, we need to use `mb_strtolower()` instead of `strtolower()` while we're working with utf-8 data:

```
$str = 'برنامه';
echo strtolower($str);
----------------------
output: �����
```

It's all gone to undefined chars, now I use `mb_strtolower()`

```
$str = 'برنامه';
echo mb_strtolower($str);
----------------------
output: �����
```

still the same results, now:

```
$str = 'برنامه';
echo mb_strtolower($str,  mb_detect_encoding($str));
----------------------
output: برنامه
```

Now it's fixed, so the way to use `mb_strtolower` is to also having `mb_detect_encoding`.

Now my problem is that I want to do the same thing with `array_map`:

```
$results_array = array_map('mb_strtolower', $results_array);
```

How I'm supposed to use `mb_detect_encoding` with the above line?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The solution is to tell `mb_strtolower` what your string encoding is:

```
echo mb_strtolower($str, 'UTF-8');
```

If you don't want to supply this parameter every time, set it once for all `mb_` functions:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Then you can call any `mb_` function and it will handle your string as UTF-8:

```
echo mb_strtolower($str); // works without second parameter now
```

`mb_detect_encoding` happens to return `'UTF-8'` because it detected it, but it is generally unreliable, since it's conceptually impossible to reliably detect arbitrarily encoded strings. *Know* what your strings are encoded in and pass this information explicitly.

Answer (score 10):

Simply put, define your own function which then calls `mb_strtolower` with `mb_detect_encoding`.

```
$results_array = array_map(function($var) {
      return mb_strtolower($var, mb_detect_encoding($var));
}, $results_array);
```

Comment: Way to overcomplicate a solution. :-P